# Filter the display of table cells with jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

I have a table structure like the one below and I would like to use JQuery to filter the display of the table cells when I click on a link. For example, if I had a link that looked like this `<a href="#" title="cat">show cats</a>` I would like to hide all the table cells besides those that contained the word "cat" in them. I am thinking that I could use a combination of "attr", "contains" and "hide/show", so I can grab the title attribute of the link I am clicking on and then match it up with the text in the table cell and finally show/hide the cells I want, but theory and implementation are 2 different things, and I am not even sure if this would work or how to put it all together so I thought I would ask the experts here for some advise.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td> 
    <td>cat</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td>dog</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>horse</td>
    <td>horse</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();  // prevents default action of the anchor
   var con = $(this).attr('title');
   $('td').hide();
   $('td:contains("'+ con +'")').show()
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LkEkA/)

Comment: This works wonders thank you very much. Only 1 small question if it's not to much to ask. How would I show all the cells again w/out refreshing the page with something like a show all link. Thanks again.

Comment: wonderful, thank you so much again. I hope I did not take up to much of your time on the 2nd request since it was not part of my original question.

Answer (score 1):

For this example I have given the table an id of `tableSelector` -

```
<table id="tableSelector"></table>
```

---

```
$("a.toggle_link").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var cells = $("#tableSelector td");
  var searchString = $(this).attr('title');
  cells.hide();
  $("#tableSelector td:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
});
```

For each `<a class="toggle_link">` that is clicked, this code will hide all of the cells, then inspect the title of the clicked `<a>` and only display the cell containing that text.

Don't forget the `preventDefault()` function.  This will prevent the default behavior of clicking on an `<a>` tag with no real `href` - usually jumping to the top of the screen.

Comment: Hmm, I was not able to make this work. Maybe because I have spaces in the titles but so do the table cells so not sure why it would not work for me.

Comment: Did you make the changes to the table element?  Adding an id to it? Also to the `<a>` tags?

Comment: I just refreshed and saw your additional comments so I am sure it will work now, but I already gave the credit to undefined :( Thanks tho for your help. Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: No problem!  It's always good to have more than one answer - that way people can choose the one that is easiest for them. Happy coding!